# Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function. Prove that the following two statements are equivalent:

Tags: functions, real-numbers

(i) $f$ is continuous and satisfies $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, and there exists $k\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(k)\ne k$.

(ii) There exists a real number $k$ and a function $g:(-\infty,k]\to[k,\infty)$ such that $g$ is a strictly decreasing bijective continuous function and satisfies
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&(x\le k)\\
g^{-1}(x)&(x>k)\end{cases}$$for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

I'm really out of ideas ... can anyone give at least one idea?

Proving that (ii) implies (i) is the easy part, but proving that (i) implies (ii) is the hard part.

Comment: Can't you even prove that $f(f(x)) = x$ if $f$ has the specified form?

Comment: Did you try ii) implies i)?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Proving that (ii) implies (i) is the easy part, but proving that (i) implies (ii) is the hard part.

Comment: $f$ is injective because if $f(x) =f(y)$, then $x=f(f(x)) = f(f(y)) = y$. So, $f$ is either strictly increasing of decreasing. Assume $f$ is increasing, Then $f(k)<k$ implies $k = f(f(k)) < f(k)$. Contradiction! Similar for $f(k)>k$. So $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume (i).
Being an involution, $f$ is bijective.
As $f$ is continuous, this is only possible if $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Assume $f$ is strictly increasing and consider $k$ with $f(k)\ne k$.
If $f(k)>k$ then as $f$ is increasing, $f(f(k))>f(k)$ - but $f(f(k))=k$, contradiction.
Similarly, if $f(k)<k$, then $f(f(k))<f(k)$, contradiction.
We conclude that $f$ is strictly decreasing.
But then we cannot have $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, nor can we have $f(x)<x$ for all $x$.
Using the IVT, we find $x_0$ with $f(x_0)=x_0$. As $f$ is strictly decreasing, we conclude that $f(x)>x_0$ for $x<x_0$ and $f(x)<x_0$ for $x>x_0$. Hence $g:=f|_{(-\infty,x_0]}$ is a map $(-\infty,0]\to[x_0,\infty)$ and clearly must be continuous and onto. By the involutory property, it follows that $f|_{[x_0,\infty)}$  is $g^{-1}$.

Comment: This solution is perfect!