# f(f(x))=x, for all x>0, then prove f is strictly decreasing. Given the fact that f is not an identity function and is also differentiable.

Tags: calculus

I tried using chain rule on $f(f(x))=x$ and ended up with $f'(f(x))*f'(x)=1$, but that means either both of them should be positive, which implies strictly increasing, or both negative, which implies strictly decreasing. Now, I don't see any way to the conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Basic MathJax isn't that hard, see [what has been changed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4432764/revisions).

Comment: You may need $f:\mathbb R^+ \to  R^+$ to avoid examples such as $f(x)=-\frac1{x}$ on $x \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo I assume $f(x)=x$ is excluded by "not an identity function"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function. Prove that the following two statements are equivalent:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405025/let-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-be-a-function-prove-that-the-following-two-statem)

Comment: @Henry In that example $f(x)$ is not in the domain $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I spite of all the criticism and counter-examples here the result is correct with the understanding that the domain of $f$ is  $(0,\infty)$. There are no counter-examples.

Comment: @MartinR If you read my answer carefully I think the domain $(0,\infty)$ plays a crucial role and I don't think this is a duplicate of the result in your link.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I have retracted my closing vote. But the question does not tell what the domain or codomain of the function is. peek-a-boo's example $f(x) = -1/x$ *does* satisfy $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $ x > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumptions are implicit: $f$ is a function from $(0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb R$ and $f(f(x))$ is defined for all $x>0$. This implies that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. [The counter-examples in comments above do not work because of these facts].

Any continuous one-to-one function on $(0,\infty)$ is strictly monotonic. Here, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=f(f(x))=f(f(y))=y$ so $f$ is one-to-one.  [Note that differentiabilty is not used!].

Suppose $f$ is strictly increasing. If $f(x)<x$ for some $x$ the $x=f(f(x))<f(x)$, a contradiction. Similarly, $f(x)>x$ for some $x$ leads to a contradictin. Hence, $f$ must be the identity function.

Answer (score 1):

The title statement is wrong; $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ is a counterexample. To get the correct statement, you need to add the hypothesis (as @Henry mentions in the comments) that $f$ maps $(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$.

From $f(f(x))=x$, we get as you mentioned, $f'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)=1$. First of all, this implies for all $x$, that $f'(x)\neq 0$. Next, Darboux's theorem on intermediae value property of derivatives implies that $f'$ maintains a constant sign. So either $f'>0$ or $f'<0$. In the first case, you have strictly increasing, and in the second, strictly decreasing.

If you now have the assumption $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ and is not identity, then @KaviRamaMurthy's answer tells you why $f$ must be strictly decreasing.

Comment: The question was changed from increasing to decreasing

Comment: @Henry ok, but still the title is wrong; $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I'm really sorry, that was typo. The problem is to prove f to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: @D.HannibalLëçter if all you know is $f(f(x))=x$ and $f$ is differentiable, then the only conclusion you can draw is $f$ is strictly increasing, or $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: what If the domain of "f" is restricted to be x>0?

Comment: Not, the conclusion is correct. See my answer now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok fair enough. Your nice answer makes use of the fact that $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$  (which OP really should have included in the hypotheses), and this excludes, as Henry mentions the counterexample of $-1/x$.

Comment: There is a problem with that counter-example if the domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$ . Note that $f(x)$ is not in the domain of $f$ in that example. @peek-a-boo