Proving that a function is strictly decreasing
Question:
Let $g$ : ($0,\infty$) $ \rightarrow$ ($0,\infty$) be a differentiable function whose derivative is continuous such that $g(g(x)) = x$ for all $x>0$. If g is not the identity function, prove that g must be strictly decreasing.
My appraoch:
$g(g(x))=x$
Differentiating, we get
$(g'(g(x))g'(x)=1$
To prove that it is strictly decreasing, we have to prove that $ g'(x) <0$
So, $\frac{1}{g'(g(x))}<0$
So, $g'(g(x))<0$
We know that $g(x)>0$ as range of g(x) is given, But how do we prove this?
Context
This is a problem in my sheet for high school level Maths.

@TedShifrin I know, it was a typo

@geetha290krm how do we know it is injective?

Any injective continuous function from $(0,\infty)$ to itself is strictly monotonic.

Obvious from the equation $g(g(x))=x$.

Note that $g=g^{-1}$. Think about the graph. Show that if $g$ is increasing, then $g$ must be the identity function.

@TedShifrin how to show that?

That’s for you to work on. Start with pictures and remember how to get the graph of the inverse.

This question already has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432765/7515
